# Is it possible to use a magnetic striped card with no emv chip to clone a credit or debit card with EMV chip inserted

Tags: emv

If a credit card or debit card has a emv chip can it be successfully cloned onto a credit or debit card that does not possess a emv chip

If so how does that work and will the ATM accept it

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully someone can provide a more authoritative answer, but I developed a point of sale application years ago and I seem to remember there is one tag which provides the track 2 equivalent data: EMV [tag 57](https://emvlab.org/emvtags/show/t57/). So it might be possible to clone the track 2 to magstrip. What I can't remember for sure is whether those tags become available only *after* entering the PIN code.

Will the ATM accept it ? Not so sure, even with the appropriate PIN code and provided necessary checksums are present. The data may not be exactly identical to what is written on the magstrip... sentinel, checksum etc. In fact, the magnetic strip may even be empty for security purposes, depending on the bank - it's common in Europe at least and something to keep in mind if you plan to travel to areas where EMV is not widespread.

The problem is the **service code**. Pure magstrip cards (becoming a rarity) have service codes starting with 1 eg: 101. Whereas chip cards use services codes in the 2xx range eg: 201. So if you try to use such a card on a payment terminal or ATM with the magstrip, the terminal can tell that the card is fitted with a chip, and will usually insist on the chip. Although they are fallback mechanisms. Maybe the EMV specification touch on that particular issue. It could depend on the amount, the accumulated purchases, whether the transaction goes online or offline, or other risk factors.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the answer above >>>
The problem is the service code. Pure magstrip cards have service codes starting with 1 eg: 101. Whereas chip cards use services codes in the 2xx range eg: 201. So if you try to use such a card on a payment terminal or ATM with the magstrip, the terminal can tell that the card is fitted with a chip, and will usually insist on the chip.

But if you are cloning the card-- You can change the service code to 101
Then the machine will think its a mag stripe only card and wont prompt you for the chip

Comment: Welcome to the community. So you're saying by changing it to 101 you can exploit this flaw in 2024? o.O I find that hard to believe

Comment: I thought chips are mandatory nowadays..